# Integration problem. Two different answers.

Tags: integration

> The variables x and y are related by the differential equation
>
> $$x \frac {dy}{dx} = 1 − y^2$$.
>
> When x = 2, y = 0. Solve the differential equation, obtaining an expression for y in terms of x.

I reached the point where

$$\frac12\int\frac1{1-y}+\frac1{1+y}dy=ln|x|+C$$

(after rearranging and doing partial fractions)

now I have a problem integrating the term $\frac1{1-y}$. There are 2 ways:

answers' way: $-\frac{-1}{1-y}$ yielding $-ln|1-y|$

my way: $-\frac1{y-1}$ yielding $-ln|y-1|$

I think both should be correct since $y-1$ is the same function as $1-y$ BELOW THE MODULUS SIGN. Later when I have to get rid of the mod sign I get a different answer than that in the answers. I mean:

answers' final answer: $y=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}$

my final answer: $y=\frac{x^2+4}{x^2-4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note your answer is the inverse of the book answer, so their logs are negatives of each other. You have to choose the correct one. The book answer agrees with the given initial condition, while yours does not.

Comment: But $$y=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}<1$$ What if $y>1?$

Comment: @lab Then you would choose the other one. It would blow up as $x \to 2$

Comment: !! didn't notice that! so later on I think when I get stuck in such a situation I'll try looking at "the condition provided". Thanks :D I sill wanna make sure though; if the condition wasn't stated then both final answers are right, right?

Comment: Yes. They are both solutions to the differential equation. You lost the constant of integration, also

Comment: yeah. okay thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

We have $$2C+2\ln|x|=\int\frac{dy}{y+1}-\int\frac{dy}{y-1}$$

$$2C+2\ln|x|=\ln\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|$$

$$x=2,y=0\implies 2C+2\ln2=\ln|-1|=0\iff C=-\ln2$$

$$\implies\ln\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|=2(\ln|x|-\ln2)=\ln\left|\frac{x}2\right|^2$$

Now for real $x,\dfrac{x^2}4\ge0$ and $\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}$ is undefined if $y-1=0$

So, if $\displaystyle\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}\ge0\iff y>1$ or $\displaystyle y\le-1, \dfrac{x^2}4=\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}$

Else (i.e., if $\displaystyle -1\le y<1), \frac{x^2}4=-\frac{y+1}{y-1}=\frac{1+y}{1-y}$

Apply [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo)

Comment: Writing a solution explicitly in terms of x is not always a good thing, which is clear from this example. I like the general solution as you stated and then from there determining the value of C based on the initial condition. (+1) That's good enough. I sometimes do not understand why people want to have solutions in the y= form at this level (Particularly when there are possible discontinuities)

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee I'm sorry I really can't understand. (the last 2 lines where there are are inequalities)

Comment: @MinaMichael, $$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=0\implies y=-1$$ for finite $y$ If $$\frac{y+1}{y-1}>0,$$  Multiplying either sides by $(y-1)^2>0$ $$ (y+1)(y-1)>0$$  What can we say about the range of $y$?

Comment: the range is y>1 or y<-1. but why is the function only greater than zero in the first place?